# How to block multiple sessions on single account

Tags: fusionauth

I'd like to better understand the role of and techniques used in FusionAuth to manage or limit multiple sessions attempted for a single user's account in our app.

Multiple sessions could be launched from a single laptop using one or more browsers. A single IP address would be linked to this batch of session requests.

Multiple sessions could be launched from multiple devices on a network segment - which may or may not present as multiple IP addresses.

And then we have the possibility of multiple sessions from many different networks.

I'm unaware of what best practices are for this. Our app is essentially stateless / session-less in the backend. FusionAuth doesn't seem to reject multiple session requests but it might be best positioned to do exactly this.

If we want to limit the active session count for each user - does this need to be handled in some middle layer that sits above FusionAuth?

Answer (score 1):

FusionAuth does not currently limit the number of active sessions a user may have in your application or in our SSO.

There are many potential types of limits that could be put in place, such as limiting by IP, device, geographic location, session count, etc that these types of limits may be best solved by a Web Application Firewall (WAF) or some other specialized network security product.